# System of nonlinear second order ODEs - Elimination Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, classical-mechanics

Two coupled nonlinear mechanical oscillators are represented by the set of differential equations:

$$\ddot{x} + \xi_1 \dot{x} + x - \gamma_1 z-\gamma_3z^3 - \xi_2\dot{z}=f(t)$$

$$\mu \ddot{z}+\gamma_1 z + \gamma_3 z^3 + \xi_2\dot{z}=-\mu \ddot{x}$$

both $x$ and $z$ are functions of time ($x(t)$, $z(t)$) and the overdot is the time derivative.

I am seeking a method to obtain only one ODE (4th order), which can be written in terms of $x$ or $z$, using the elimination method.

I have tried the operator method writing the two equations as

$$ \left(D^2 + \xi_1 D + 1\right)x - \left(\gamma_1 + \gamma_3 z^2 +\xi_2 D \right) z = f(t)$$
$$ \left(\mu D^2 + \gamma_1 + \gamma_3 z^2  + \xi_2 D\right)z + \mu D^2 x = 0$$

where $D = \frac{d}{dt}$

How to proceed from here? (Can this be done using computer algebra software ?)

Comment: You can take the derivative of the first equation two times, take the derivative of the second equation two times and use those results to eliminate $x$.

Comment: Add the two equations together. This gives a single second order differential equation of $x$ in terms of $z’’$ and $f$. You can the solve using Laplace transform

Comment: @player100 there is a nonlinear term $z^3$. I don't think Laplace transform will work. Actually I don't want to find an analytical solution. I just need to find the an equation in terms of one variable, say $z$

Comment: @Moo. Yes, thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 1):

Derive the first equation twice regarding time giving

$$
x^{(4)}+\xi_1x^{(3)}+x^{(2)}-\gamma_1 z^{(2)}-\gamma_3(6z \dot z^2+3z^2z^{(2)})-\xi_2z^{(3)}=f^{(2)}
$$

and now use (derive) the second equation to obtain $x^{(4)}, x^{(3)}$ and then substitute into the first.

Answer (score 0):

Add the two equations together.

$$(1+\mu)x''+\xi_1x'+x = -\mu z''+ f(t)$$

Notice, that $(1+\mu)[x''+\frac{\xi_1}{1+\mu}x'+{1\over{1+\mu}}x]= (1+\mu)(D+\alpha)(D+\beta)x$, where $\alpha + \beta = \frac{\xi_1}{1+\mu}$ and $\alpha\beta={1\over{1+\mu}}$.

Now $(D+c)g=e^{-ct}\frac{d}{dt}(e^{ct}g)$. So, expanding the $lhs$ above, we get

$$(1+\mu)e^{-\alpha t}\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\alpha t} \left[e^{-\beta t}\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\beta t} x) \right] \right)=(1+\mu)e^{-\alpha t}\frac{d}{dt}\left( e^{(\alpha - \beta )t} \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\beta t} x) \right)$$

Substituting this back into the original equation we see
$$(1+\mu)e^{-\alpha t}\frac{d}{dt}\left( e^{(\alpha - \beta) t} \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\beta t} x) \right) = -\mu z'' + f(t)$$

We solve for $x$ as follows
$$e^{(\alpha - \beta) t} \frac{d}{dt}(e^{\beta t} x)= \int{}-\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}e^{\alpha t}z'' + {1\over{1+\mu}}e^{\alpha t}f dt.$$

Using integration by parts,
$$\begin{align}
\int{}-\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}e^{\alpha t}z'' dt &= -\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}\left(z'e^{\alpha t}-\int \alpha e^{\alpha t} z'dt\right) \\
&=-\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}\left(z'e^{\alpha t}-\left[\alpha e^{\alpha t}z-\int \alpha^2 e^{\alpha t} z dt\right]\right)
\end{align}$$
Simplifying,
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\beta t} x) = -\frac{\mu}{1+\mu}e^{\beta t}\left(z'- \alpha z + \int \alpha^2 e^{\alpha (\tau - t)} z d\tau - {1\over\mu} \int e^{\alpha (\tau - t)} f d\tau\right)$$
In similar fashion, we can do the final integration and find $x$ in terms of $z$ and $f$.

Because I do not want to bore you with the derivation, let me show you how you could get a similar result with Laplace's transform. Let $X$,$Z$,$F$ be transforms of $x$,$z$,$f$ respectively. Then, the first equation becomes
$$\begin{align}
\left[(1+\mu)s^2+\xi_1s+1\right]X &= -\mu s^2Z+ F\\
X &= \frac{-\mu s^2}{(1+\mu)s^2+\xi_1s+1}Z + \frac{1}{(1+\mu)s^2+\xi_1s+1}F \\
X &= \frac{-\mu}{1+\mu} \frac{s^2 Z}{(s+\alpha)(s+\beta)}+\frac{1}{1+\mu} \frac{F}{(s+\alpha)(s+\beta)} \\
X &= \frac{-\mu}{1+\mu}\left(1+\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\left[\frac{\alpha^2}{s+\alpha}-\frac{\beta^2}{s+\beta}\right]\right)Z + \\
&\frac{1}{1+\mu} \frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\left({1\over{s+\alpha}}-{1\over{s+\beta}}\right)F
\end{align}$$

You can then apply the inverse transform of terms of the form ${1\over{s+c}}Y$, which is $e^{ct}\ast y(t)$, with appropriate assumptions about the support of the signals, namely that they don't extend from 0 to $-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your hard work @player100, however as I mentioned in my question, I need to write the system in terms of $x$ or $z$ only. In your development $X$ is written as a function of $Z$.

Comment: Yes but then you can substitute the expression back into the second equation... take the derivative of $x$ twice.